# Is there a way to force two parameter slices to have the same length?

Tags: rust

If I want to define a function like so:

```
fn f(in_slice: &[T], out_slice: &mut [T]){
}
```

Is there any way to guarantee at compile time that the two slices have the same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because compiler does not know the lengths at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Comment: Whether the score for this answer be 50 or -50, it’s still the simple truth.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Try adding *why*.

Comment: @bjb568: sure it’s an answer. A thing like is being requested is not even a vaguely common language feature—the significant majority of professional programmers have never used a programming language where it’s possible. There is nothing to explain about why—it’s just like all the other normal languages.

Comment: 2 characters just can't be an answer on SE. Another possibility is for you to comment that you can't and ask why OP wants to since this looks like an X/Y problem.

Comment: I realize rust isn't dependently typed. But I thought there might be a way to make the function a generic on the number of elements in the slice. Like fn f<T,N>(in_slice &[T,N], out_slice &[T,N]) or something.

Comment: @DurnWhippersnapper: it’s not. Slices are a purely runtime construct.

Comment: @bjb568 this is an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Not yet. It's likely that we will at some point [gain support](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/56) for `uint`s in generics, after which it should become possible, something like:

```
fn f<T, static N: uint>(in_slice: &[T, ..N], out_slice: &mut [T, ..N]) { ... }
```

Comment: This still won't necessarily do the precisely right thing: it will be taking pointers to known-at-compile-time fixed-length arrays, meaning you always have to be passing around the `.. N`, and can't ever handle the erased `&[T]` version (because it's not possible to write a function that goes from `v: &[T]` to `&[T, .. v.len()]` for an arbitrary `v`).

Comment: Yes. I have a solution for that, but this margin isn't large enough to explain it. :)

Comment: You could add it to your answer.

Comment: I'm going to submit an RFC for it, and it's not going to be short.